# Start child process process inside parent process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is it possible to start a child process inside same address space?
I would like to access any exported function localy.

ex:

1. Start (launcher) process (parent).
2. (launcher) calls CreateProcess(...) (child process)

but the child process will have a new address space, am I correct? Is there any way to CreateProcess inside parent process address space? I know that it's possible to access it externally but would like to do it in elegant way.

Comment: What's the rationale for this?

Comment: I would like to access exported function from the address space.

Comment: A DLL is mapped into the address space of its calling process, my first question still applies I think

Comment: but this is another executable file, not a dynamic library I can just map it into parent process but what is the purpose of it because I still cannot run it.

Comment: @user2887378 You probably should [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35321602/edit) and tell a bit more about your motivations. As it is you have a XY-problem. As far I could read from your comments you have the problem you need to connect from proprietary (non disclosed) code with a GPLed shared library.

Comment: Arguably the most important defining characteristic of a process is having a unique address space. So having a process with the same address space as another process doesn't make much sense. The other defining characteristics of a Windows process such as the set of resources it owns, its (usual) mapping to a specific user, its (usual) mapping to a fixed set of Windows stations, its mapping to a "NT subsystem", etc. are all malleable (except NT subsystem): they can be shared, their usual mapping changed,  their settings copied, etc. - so aren't as unique as the address space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to start a child process inside same address space? I would like to access any exported function localy.

No, it's not possible. The operating system creates a new address space for each process, that is protected to be accessed from other processes.

Use threads instead.

Comment: Yeah, but it has to be another executable because the child process is on GPL license and I cannot load any dynamic library without source code opening, but this code has to be closed. I need to inject dll into a child process then, thanks.

Comment: @user2887378 Well, then try to get something that uses a LGPL license, or wrap that stuff in a separate process and use IPC mechanisms (may be shared memory).

Comment: @user2887378: The GPL does not make a distinction between processes or libraries. All it cares about is, if you're using GPL-ed code directly. Calling directly functions from a different process image would still be considered library linking by the GPL.

Comment: @datenwolf I 1st thought so as well, but the OP states that the DLL will be linked into a separate executable.

Comment: I ment another executable not a dynamic library, the child process (gpl) exporting a function which I would call it from a parent.

Comment: @user2887378: That doesn't make a difference. You want to directly call a function from a different binary. That makes this binary a library. It doesn't matter if this thing is designated a "executable" or a "DLL". To the operating system a DLL is the same thing as an EXE, with the only difference being, that an EXE has an entry point that gets called at launch, while a DLL just sits there. But it is perfectly possible to create a DLL, that can also be "launched". And as a matter of fact you can export symbols from EXEs and load a EXE with `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @user2887378: Heck, you could even write a linker `.def` that will make the liker to link an `.exe` to another `.exe`. The file format used by DLLs, EXEs, and all the other Windows executable binaries is the same. It's called PE and the OS kernel does not distinguish between them. On Linux it's the same BTW; just with ELF instead of PE. And when it comes to the GPL directly calling a function into a binary loaded into the same address space (which is what you want to do) counts as linkage.

Comment: @datenwolf The point could be solved maybe, you have a GPLed DLL, and provide an executable wrapper that's also under GPL and provides whatever kind of IPC, not?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, that would be a valid approach. What the GPL forbids is linkage, i.e. directly calling a piece of GPL code, from another piece of code that's not GPL license compatible. IPC is not direct linkage. I guess if it were for RMS then even IPC should be GPL-ed, but then each and every network interaction is essentially IPC (through several layers).

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to access any exported function locally.

You do not need the child process to share the same memory space as the parent.  Calling [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) with the parent process's executable will provide the child process access to exported entrypoints in the parent. Note that this will *not* provide a mechanism to share memory (unless you're actually using [shared memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686958(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Yeah, im going to use shared memory or injecting module into a child process, just wanted to be sure if that would be possible. Thank you @MooseBoys for the LoadLibrary info, appreciate.